# How do I use Chrome Web Developer to examine tipsy hover overs?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, tipsy

I am trying to inspect the div element that appears for Tipsy hover-overs on this page in order to change the width of the popup.
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1531353/Misc/Docudocker/setups/tipsyCrashingApplication/force-html.html

However, when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and then move my mouse to the Developer Elements panel, the Tipsy hover-over disappears, so I can't examine it any more.

How do I examine an element that only appears upon a hover-over effect in Chrome Web Developer?

Comment: I tried doing right click and select Inspect element but my browser hanged and the CPU utilization jumped to 100%.

Comment: haha same here. Wow, that was interesting. Perhaps I need to use more efficient algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Win 7. I used `firebug` & it showed that tooltips were using the `tipsy.css` try to navigate to your tipsy css & change the `width` attrib though i couldnt get the bottom part of the tooltip in right shape. Hope it helps[image]